# Can I make alias commands on redis-cli?

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redisclient

I have the impression Im always typing again and again the same commands

```
ZRANGE mykey 0 100 WITHSCORES
```

and it is quite repetitive as I have to juggle between maps, sets, and sorted sets (and the client is not great, I can't use the same shortcuts that I use in my terminal to delete the previous/next word for instance)

Is there a way, like in bash, to write our own scripts to make our life easier ?

e.g

```
LISTALL mykey
```

Comment: there is lua. https://www.redisgreen.net/blog/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/

Comment: you can use Lua script http://redis.io/commands/eval.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redis from `bash` with `redis-cli` if that is what you mean?

Then you can make `bash` aliases. So, in `bash`:

```
function LISTALL() { redis-cli "ZRANGE $1 0 100 WITHSCORES"; }
```

then you can do

```
LISTALL mykey
```

and use `bash` editing.

Comment: I meant inside the redis-cli (I have many redis instances I connect to). though your solution is a good idea